# Is there standard way to get numerical consistency in Julia

Tags: julia, numerical-methods, zero

```
└─╼ julia 
 Version 0.6.0 (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)  
 julia> 1.0 + 0.1 - 1.0 - 0.1 == 0
  false  
 julia> 1.0 + 0.1 - 1.0 - 0.1
  8.326672684688674e-17
```

i understand that decimals like 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in binary based point without some additional effort e.g.

```
julia> 1//10
 1//10
julia> 1 + 1//10
 11//10
julia> 1 + 1//10 - 1
 1//10
julia> 1 + 1//10 - 1 - 1//10
 0//1
julia> 1 + 1//10 - 1 - 1//10 == 0
 true
```

or going purely symbolic.

there are several rounding options:
    julia> Round
    RoundDown            RoundNearest          RoundNearestTiesUp    RoundUp
    RoundFromZero        RoundNearestTiesAway  RoundToZero     RoundingMode

Without launching into a protracted discussion of numerical stability, does Julia have a recommended style?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really isn't a question about Julia. This will show up in any language using IEEE floating point arithmetic, since Julia just uses the standard. So the standard rules apply.

1. Don't expect floating point calculations to be exact. Instead, test floating point sameness using `isapprox` (or `\approx` for ≈) with a tolerance set appropriately.
2. If you need true decimals, you should use rationals like in that example you have.
3. Another helpful thing may be DecFP.jl which uses IEEE decimal arithmetic and thus is more precise in this kind of example.
4. If you need to be more precise, use higher precision. `BigFloat`s have their purpose.

Comment: \approx for ≈  is excellent to know about, the function name seems to be isapprox rather than approx.  DecFP.jl  looks promising.  Rationals and BigFloats just move the problem for my use case.  `julia> @Base.Test.test  1 ≈ 0.9999999  atol=10.0^-7
Test Passed
julia> @Base.Test.test  1 ≈ 0.9999999  atol=10.0^-8
Test Failed`

Comment: What's your use case? You should be more specific about that. The correct way to handle floating point arithmetic depends on the application.

Comment: ≈  solves it. the deets aren't relevant.  thx for asking, tho. the Q was specifically for a Julia approach.  you've answered that quite nicely.  @james answer was interesting for delineating the addition case, in particular.  however, the  ≈ does leave the code more readable and arithmetically flexible.  granted, numerics can be treacherous.

Answer (score 3):

Also there is `sum_kbn` which may be all you need for your application:

```
julia> sum([1.0, 0.1, - 1.0, - 0.1])
8.326672684688674e-17

julia> sum_kbn([1.0, 0.1, - 1.0, - 0.1])
0.0

help?> sum_kbn
search: sum_kbn cumsum_kbn

  sum_kbn(A)

  Returns the sum of all elements of A, using the Kahan-Babuska-Neumaier compensated summation algorithm for additional accuracy.
```

Comment: thx!  inspired by your post i dug a bit and found a discussion on KBN in Julia [https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/199]. good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is useless to worry about this "inconsistency". Your number is wrong in the sixteenth decimal, which is much less than the size of an atom when you measure the circumference of the Earth.

In practice the quantities you are dealing with are measured with some resolution and accuracy, are described by approximate models and computed with truncated methods.

It matters to take care of the real sources of errors and the numerical processes that amplify them. In other words, have a feeling for error calculus. Moving to exact arithmetic is often a nonsense.